# Why doesn't the initial internal energy matter when calculating enthalpy?

Tags: material-science

Mathematically I saw that when the initial value of the internal energy is changed when making a calculation for enthalpy using the equations: ΔH = ΔU - PΔV and ΔH = Hf - Hi, it doesn't make a difference in the calculation.

However I'm not being able to understanding this intuitively, as if the value of the standard state/initial internal energy value is changed, shouldn't it have an impact on the enthalpy?

Comment: it's in the second equation, how could it not matter?

Comment: When the first equation is substituted in the second equation, Ui cancels out, thereby the value of the standard state does not make a difference.